# Connection to remote host MongoDB breaks after a certain number of inserts to the collection

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I have my Mongo DB v2.1.2 hosted on remote server. After inserting 58070 records i am getting the following message exception more often
Message = "A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)"
I have not run out of memory in the DB folder on the remote server. Is there any restriction on the number of inserts at one go. Also i have provision for all sorts of Mongo Exceptions so it is not a mongo exception just a remote connection drop. When i re run, the connection drops on the same record. When i put this on my local mongo instance it goes through without a problem.
What could be the possible reasons?